# lftp via sftp, file not found error while uploading

Tags: linux, unix, sftp, lftp

I have tried to find a soluting to this problem almost whole day, googled everywhere, serarched this forum for hours, yet i cant find out where the problem is. I have to parse application log files on hourly basis and then transfer the hourly file(containing approximately 100,00 lines) to a remore server for database upload. Use of FTP is blocked for security reasons so i am using lftp via sftp for file transfer as the script will run from cron.

problem is while uploading file by ***PUT/MPUT*** command sftp throws error "**put: '/home/applogs/ACCESS/access_log*: No such file or directory**". I am using an "*" so that any file srarting with name **access_log** is transferred. If i put the full file name (i.e.;access_log_10-06-2013_15_53_46.txt) then the script works perfectly, but if i use "**access_log***" then system cant find the file !!! I tried both PUT and MPUT.

Would be a great help if anyone could help. Below is my code for the file transfer portion:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    IP=**********
    USER=********
    PASS=********

    SRC='/home/applogs/ACCESS/'
    DST='/home/db/INPUT/'

    ###### get system time ######
    EXECU_TIME=`date '+%d-%m-%Y_%H_%M_%S'`

    ###### Rename file with system timestamp ######
    mv access_log* access_log_$EXECU_TIME.txt

    ###### Change file permission ######
    chmod 774 access_log_$EXECU_TIME.txt


    ##### Start file transfer
    lftp -u ${USER},${PASS} sftp://${IP}<<EOF>lftplog.txt
    cd ${DST}
    lcd ${SRC}
    set net:timeout 30
    set ftp:ssl-allow no
    put access_log*
    quit
    EOF
```

system information of the source: GNU Linux 2.6.9-55

system information of the destination: GNU Linux 2.6.39-200.24.1

Comment: just to add, the file is there in the SRC directory, no doubt about that

Answer (score 2):

Try `mput access_log*`   You need to tell lftp not to ask for confirmation on mput:

```
lftp -i -u  ${USER},${PASS} sftp://${IP}<<EOF>lftplog.txt
cd ${DST}
lcd ${SRC}
set net:timeout 30
set ftp:ssl-allow no
mput access_log*
quit
EOF
```

I hope you have only one access_log.* file to "put"

Comment: Thanks a lot @JimMcnamara , it's working. Yes, ideally there should be only 1 access_log_.... file. However, using an "**" would mean that if by any chance another file (maybe the file of previous hour failed to be transferred or etc. etc), that will also be transferred. That is why i wanted to use the exact file name with put. There is another workaound suggested by another blog. in the main script i can do an ls -1 with access_log*, sort by filename, write the list to a file, cat that file for the first line and put in a string variable and then use that variable inside the lftp for put